# jekyll commands output some failure

Tags: jekyll

I have something wrong with my jekyll installation. After typing however jekyll command in terminal, it outputs  following:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/converters/sass.rb:6:in
```

`<module:Converters>': uninitialized constant Jekyll::Converters::Scss (NameError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/converters/sass.rb:5:in ...`'

Anyone knows what's wrong? I have no idea. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try to `gem update` or `bundle update`. This seems to be an old bug.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with jekyll on Ubuntu 14.10. It's [been fixed](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=756845) in Debian, and [reported as a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jekyll/+bug/1422020) in Ubuntu. You can manually apply the same fix, it's just one line ([see patch](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=756845#15)) that needs to be added to a file:

1. Open `/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/converters/sass.rb`
2. Add `require 'jekyll/converters/scss'` at the top, just after `require 'jekyll/utils'`

Also make sure that the package `ruby-mercenary` is installed (`sudo apt-get ruby-mercenary`), because of [another bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jekyll/+bug/1382984).

Then Jekyll will work. Alternatively, use Rubygems: `gem install jekyll`.

Comment: Might be interesting to copy/paste the instructions here so that they are available here even when debian's somehow down.

Comment: Goode idea, done! I should credit Simon Raffeiner (sturmflut)  whose steps I copied from the Ubuntu bug.